# enabling menu link based user authentication is not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

enabling menu link based user on authentication token is not working in Reactjs. in web browser console, it should show true or false. app run with no error, i do not see any true or false

```
isUserLoggedIn(){
        let user=sessionStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser')
       if(user===null) return false
       return true
    }

const isUserLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn();
         console.log(isUserLoggedIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63682799/react-headercomponent-does-not-change-after-log-in/63683379#63683379). Plainly speaking, the fact is that react does not update the complete page, it only updates specific components based on certain events (like state change, etc).

So the problem is you're dependent on an external class `AuthenticationService` for updating `HeaderComponent` and the links available on it. However, doing so won't make `HeaderComponent` call its own `render()` again which means you need to refresh the page manually (`CTRL + R`) to see the navlinks updated on `HeaderComponent`.