# React - HeaderComponent does not change after log-in?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `TodoComponent` which has been written to show certain links on the navbar in HeaderComponent depending upon the current state of the user - whether logged-in or logged-out.

```
class TodoApp extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div className="TodoApp">
                <Router>
                        <HeaderComponent />
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={LoginComponent} />
                            <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginComponent} />
                            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/welcome/:name" exact component={WelcomeComponent} />
                            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/todos/" exact component={ListTodosComponent} />
                            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/logout" exact component={LogoutComponent} />
                            <Route component={ErrorFuncComponent} />
                        </Switch>
                        <FooterComponent />
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I feel the `HeaderComponent` does not render itself again after the user is logged-in.

```
class HeaderComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        
        const isUserLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()
        console.log(isUserLoggedIn)

        return (
            <header>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <div><a href="http://localhost:3000" className="navbar-brand">Todo Management</a></div>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        {isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/welcome/in28minutes">Home</Link></li>}
                        {isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/todos">Todos</Link></li>}
                    </ul>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
                        {!isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/login">Login</Link></li>}
                        {isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" onClick={AuthenticationService.logoutAuthenticatedUser} to="/logout">Logout</Link></li>}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

because the LogIn component does not forces?(Should I force other components? I'm not sure this is the correct way to do things)

Snippet of `LoginComponent.jsx`

```
handleLoginButtonClick = () => {

    if (this.state.username === 'zaid' && this.state.password === 'khan') {
        AuthenticationService.registerAuthenticatedUser(this.state.username, this.state.password)
        // window.location.reload(false);
        this.props.history.push(`/welcome/${this.state.username}`) //String templating //this.props.history.push("/welcome/"+this.state.username)
        this.setState(
            { isLoginSuccess: true, isLoginFailed: false }, function () {
                console.log(this.state);
            }
        )
    }
    else {
        this.setState(
            { isLoginSuccess: false, isLoginFailed: true }, function () {
                console.log(this.state);
            }
        )
    }
    // console.log(this.state)
}
```

How do I make HeaderComponent update(basically call `render` method again after the user logs-in ?!?!).

P.S. I think there might be another way to do it which involves automatically performing some action based on an event. I just don't know how it would fit with what I have done so far. I'm new to React.

This guy faced the same problem (but explained it poorly IMO): [enabling menu link based user authentication is not working in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110021/enabling-menu-link-based-user-authentication-is-not-working-in-reactjs)

Comment: I just tried that. Does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components re-render if it detects any changes in State or Props, this is what shallow compare do, so to re-render the component, it should depend on one if these, so what you can do is to use **isLoginSuccess** and pass it back to TodoComponent and then send it as a props to **HeaderComponent** like this:

```
class TodoApp extends Component {
    state = {isLoginSuccess:false}
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div className="TodoApp">
                <Router>
                        <HeaderComponent isLoginSuccess={this.state.isLoginSuccess}/>
                        
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={() => <LoginComponent isAuthed={true} onLogin={(status)=> this.setState({isLoginSuccess:status})}/>} />
                            ...
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In **LoginComponent**

```
handleLoginButtonClick = () => {
    if (this.state.username === 'zaid' && this.state.password === 'khan') {
        ...
        this.props.onLogin(true);
        ...
    }
    else {
        this.props.onLogin(false);
        ...
    }
}
```

In **HeaderComponent** replace isUserLoggedIn with isLoginSuccess:

```
class HeaderComponent extends Component {

    render() {
    let { isLoginSuccess } = this.props;
        ...
        return (
            <header>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <div><a href="http://localhost:3000" className="navbar-brand">Todo Management</a></div>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        {isLoginSuccess && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/welcome/in28minutes">Home</Link></li>}
                        ...
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

**Note: Using Redux or Context instead of passing props between components would be more structured and easy to handle**

Comment: It throws an error saying `TypeError: this.props.onLogin is not a function`.

Comment: make sure you make this change 
<Route path="/" exact component={() => <LoginComponent isAuthed={true} onLogin={(status)=> this.setState({isLoginSuccess:status})}/>} />

Comment: Yeah. It's present there.

Comment: Oh I think `/login` should be changed as well. So now after I changed it's showing a different error about how `history` is being undefined in `this.props.history.push(\`/welcome/${this.state.username}\`)`. I think it's because `history` is now no longer being passed from 'Route` component.

Comment: wrap the component with (withRouter)

Comment: Tried `<Route path="/" exact>
                        <LoginComponent isAuthed={true} onLogin={(status)=> this.setState({isLoginSuccess:status})}/>
                        </Route> 
                        
                        <Route path="/login" exact>
                        <LoginComponent isAuthed={true} onLogin={(status)=> this.setState({isLoginSuccess:status})}/>
                        </Route>`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't keep your auth status in an external class. React change detection triggers only if state or props are different (shallow compare). It cannot detect changes in an external class. Such a state can, for example, be managed with React Context.

```js
const AuthContext = React.createContext()

function AuthProvider(props) {
  const login = () => {}
  const register = () => {}
  const logout = () => {} 
  const isLoggedIn = ()=>{}
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{data, login, logout, register, isLoggedIn }} {...props} />
  )
}

export function withAuthContext(Component) {
    return function WrapperComponent(props) {
        return (
            <AuthContext.Consumerr>
                {state => <Component {...props} context={state} />}
            </AuthContext.Consumer>
        );
    };
}

export {AuthProvider, withAuthContext}
```

```
class HeaderComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        
        const isUserLoggedIn = props.context.isLoggedIn()

        return (
            <header>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <div><a href="http://localhost:3000" className="navbar-brand">Todo Management</a></div>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                        {isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/welcome/in28minutes">Home</Link></li>}
                        {isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/todos">Todos</Link></li>}
                    </ul>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
                        {!isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" to="/login">Login</Link></li>}
                        {isUserLoggedIn && <li><Link className="nav-link" onClick={props.context.logout} to="/logout">Logout</Link></li>}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}

export default withAuthContext(HeaderComponent)
```

Remember to wrap your whole React tree with `AuthProvider`.

Comment: Yeah. The problem was I was following an instructor build the complete website using React and Spring Boot. Like, I'm currently in the front-end phase so a lot of values are just hard-coded and I don't mind such errors for now. However, what bugged me is that the front-end he created was able to automatically refresh after log-in and log-out despite the fact the code is virtually the same. (He might be using an older version of React though)